# found_count deprecated for SearchResults object in GAE?

Tags: python, google-app-engine

From the GAE Python Search API docs here:
https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/search/queryoptionsclass?hl=en

Contains code:
`pages = results.found_count / page_size`

I am trying to access the 'found_count' property of a SearchResults object but getting the following error in log:

`'SearchResults' object has no attribute 'found_count'`

Has this property been deprecated? I see no other reference to 'found_count' anywhere in the GAE Search API documentation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

looks like it's been replaced by the `number_found` property, referenced elsewhere in the documentation.. the docs are out of sync!

this works: `results.number_found`